# Are there other texts Muslims consider equally holy to the Qur'an?

Tags: quran

To my understanding, the Qur'an is the holy word of God for Muslims (like the Bible is for Christians). But often I see Muslims quoting texts and scholars independent of the Qur'an and citing them as "holy texts".

**Are there any other texts that are considered holy along with the Qur'an**? Are any of these texts considered *equally* holy? If so, why are they considered as such? I'm not talking about good reading, I'm talking about other texts that are deemed as inspired by God.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Shiites are told about the existence of [other holy books](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/do-shiites-believe-in-other-holy-books-revelations-after-quran/) that were kept by each successive [Imam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imamah_%28Shia_doctrine%29) and passed to the later and are now kept by the awaited occult [Imam al-Mahdi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Imam), but these texts are not considered equally holy to the Quran despite the fact that they also contain divine revelations.

Comment: Uh-huh. I indeed admire the above-mentioned sources (posts) as you presented. I red them. Them looked helpful and proficient. God Bless You for presenting them.

Answer (score 3):

The authentic sayings of Prophet Mohamed called *ahadith* (pl. of *hadith*) are considered inspiration from God and equally "holy."

That's because the Quran says in Surah an-Najm 53:3-4 =

> Nor does he speak from desire.  It is only an Inspiration that is
>   revealed.

Muslims believe anything Prophet Mohamed said regarding religion was an inspiration from God.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Islam.

Bible as a whole is collection of God's words(Old Testament) and also Prophet Jesus'(pbuh) words (New Testament).

But, in Islam, the words of God are in a book called 'Qur'an' and

The words of Prophet Muhammad(pbuh) are collected in a book called 'Hadith'(News or Information).

We value both

> It is not for a believer, man or woman, when Allah and His Messenger have decreed a matter that they should have any option in their decision. And whoever disobeys Allah and His Messenger, he has indeed strayed in a plain error.  (Qur'an 33:36)

Only difference, few verses of Hadith(some reporting of sayings of Prophet(pbuh)) are weak(not authentic) but whereas, The Qur'an it's proven to be 110% authentic.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Muslims believing such holy texts, but it is not so right.

According to Islam, we believe that the Qur'an isn't corrupted, it is just as exactly it is announced by Prophet Mohammad(puh). (There is a claim about recm verses, but this claim isn't approved.) We also support this belief with historical facts. Qur'an is a word of Allah, thus it is the most sacred word and we have to obey it.

There are hadiths (Prophet's words and actions), which are collected in various books and are separated from Qur'an. Hadiths are considered as 3 groups:

1. **Genuine ones:** They are also sacred, but not as sacred as Qur'an. We have to obey them too.
2. **Non-genuine ones:** They are made up, they have no historical support, they have contradictions with Qur'an. They certainly aren't sacred, we have to avoid them.
3. **Controversial ones:** We have to be very careful about them and leave the decide to determine whether they are genuine to the scholars.

We know that by [Surat An-Najm 53/1-4](http://quran.com/53/1-4), Mohammad(puh) didn't act against Allah. But, his actions and words were told by his nearby and collected later from his death. Some hadiths are proven that they are made up. Made up ones are not sacred of course, but his true words and actions are sacred, because they are the explanations of Qur'an and their practices. Some hadiths are genuine, but relevant to his time and conditions. For example the amount of zakat. This is why hadiths are not as sacred as Qur'an. Qur'an's rules and limits are for all time and conditions, they can't be adjusted.

There are also tafseer (explanation of Qur'an) books written by scholars. They are comments and conclusions of their authors, sometimes contradicting each other. Many Muslims behave that as they are sacred, but I think they are not. Because they are not actual words, but comments and conclusions, they may be wrong. Scholars are humans and can make mistakes.